# Vue router passing props is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to pass a props via the vue router with the router link looks like this

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'product-details', params: { productId: 123 } }" class="product-sbb d-block">
```

And this is my routes

```
{
  path: '/product/details/:productId',
  name: 'product-details',
  props: true,
  components: {
   navbar: Navbar,
   default: ProductDetail,
   footer: Footer
 },
},
```

I have set the props to true and also add the params to the path **/:productId**. I also follow the example from this link
https://codesandbox.io/s/o41j762pnz

I'm trying to pass that props to my component, but when I want to use that props in my component, the props always **undefined**.
Here's my component

```
import ProductDetail from '../components/parts/ProductDetailGallery.vue';

export default {
  props: {
    productId: Number
  },
  data() {
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.productId)
  }
}
```

I did exactly like the example, the example run perfect without any issue, but mine didn't. How do I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your CodeSandbox where it does not work?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I'm sorry for the long wait, here's the link https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-galileo-0m959?file=/src/main.js

please ignore the messed html, because I didn't load the css, if you look at the console, it shows undefined

Comment: For routes with named views, you need to define props for each individual view you want to pass the param into: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Comment: @Terry I did what you say, it still the same undefined, i did something like this

 `{
    path: '/product/details',
    name: 'product-details',
    props: {
      productId: Number
    },
    components: {
      navbar: Navbar,
      default: ProductDetail,
      footer: Footer
    },
  },`

Comment: @Villian You're doing it incorrectly. Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using [named views in your router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode), you cannot just declare `prop: true`. You will have to declare that explicitly on each view that you want to receive the parameter. This can be done by changing how `prop` is defined. This is how you're doing it now, which will *not* work:

```
props: true
```

The correct way:

```
props: {
    // You must set `true` to the default view, which uses ProductDetail
    default: true
}
```

So your routes should look like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/product/details/:productId",
    name: "product-details",
    components: {
      navbar: Navbar,
      default: ProductDetail,
      footer: Footer
    },
    props: {
      // You must set `true` to the default view, which uses ProductDetail
      default: true
    }
  }
];
```